# Could not bind socket. Address and port are already in use - using TIdSMTPServer and TIdPop3Server

Tags: delphi, smtp, indy, pop3

I've probably read dozens of answers and topics through the web, but I'm still missing something in order to fix this error. I have a `TIdPop3Server` and a `TIdSMTPServer` and I want to activate them, but I just can't do it successfully. I've set the `ReuseSocket` property of both to `rsTrue` and I'm not leaving the `Bindings` empty when I try to set them both to `.Active := True;` This is how my code looks like :

```
with POP3Server do begin
  ReuseSocket := rsTrue;
  Active := False;
  Bindings.Clear;
  DefaultPort := 110;
  Bindings.Add.IP := myIpAddr;
end;
with SMTPServer do begin
  ReuseSocket := rsTrue;
  Active := False;
  Bindings.Clear;
  DefaultPort := 25;
  Bindings.Add.IP := myIpAddr;
end;
```

And I have a `TButton` that I click where this is called :

```
SMTPServer.Active := True;
Pop3Server.Acive := True;
```

If someone had already fixed this problem can he tell me how he had done it (hope I didn't already read his answer somewhere else ...)

Comment: Please tell wich server is failing to start. My guess are POP3Server and it could be your email program blocking the port

Comment: Both servers give the same error.

Comment: Then you must find do a NETSTAT in order for knowing what is blocking your ports.

Answer (score 5):

You did not say which server is failing to bind.  But there is nothing to fix really.  Something else on your machine, likely an antivirus or firewall, is already using one of those ports.  Use a tool like Netstat or TCPViewer to find out which process is using those ports.